# Failed to read schema document spring xsd

Tags: java, spring, xsd, xsd-validation, spring-bean

I know it's a common problem but I tried a lot of solutions already proposed here and none of them works :/

I had an existing project which runs on an old Jboss 4.2.3.
So I'm migrating it to Wildfly 8.
I have the 4.0.6 spring version configured in my pom.xml everywhere in project.

In my databaseBeans.xml I had 2.5 version of xsd configured before migration, so I put the new version :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd">

    <bean id="mappingList" class="java.util.ArrayList">
```

But I'm getting :

```
2022-06-29 10:38:20,980 WARN  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] (default task-2) Ignored XML validation warning: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 76; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:196)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.warning(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:390)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:304)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaWarning(XSDHandler.java:4112)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument1(XSDHandler.java:2462)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(XSDHandler.java:2160)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:557)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:580)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2716)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2079)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:788)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:283)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:733)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1754)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:324)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:875)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:798)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:108)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:230)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
```

I tried also removing the -4.0.xsd to let spring choose but same error :

```
2022-06-29 10:51:25,429 WARN  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] (default task-1) Ignored XML validation warning: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 72; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:196)
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.warning(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:390)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:304)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaWarning(XSDHandler.java:4112)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument1(XSDHandler.java:2462)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(XSDHandler.java:2160)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:557)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:580)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2716)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2079)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:788)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:283)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:733)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1754)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:324)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:875)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:798)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:108)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:230)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:428) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
```

In the jar listed in the end of this stacktrace (spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE), I have check in META-INF/spring.schemas and I have :

```
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-2.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-2.5.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-4.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-4.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-2.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-2.5.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-4.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-4.0.xsd
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

EDIT :

I try to debug the code, and when the XML is read, I see a difference between Jboss version and Wildly version.

Jboss version with a "UnifiedClassLoader" has dozen of "packages" loaded in it (included spring-beans and others things) :

[image]

Wildfly version with a "ModuleClassLoader" has only 2 packages, and not the spring-beans jar :

[image]

It seems to be a problem with my two files for my App : 1 war and 1 .ear file.

The .ear file is not loaded like Jboss, and miss the spring dependencies.

But why in the stack trace we see "spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar" mentioned in this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully solved the problem following this tutorial :

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/168093

Briefly, I create a modules/org/springframework/spring/main/module.xml file, with the spring jar in resources.
I copy the spring jar already present in tmp/deployment/vfs on the server in this directory : modules/org/springframework/spring/main/
And then I create a jboss-deployment-structure in my app and add the spring modules.

But, I don't really understand why I need to do all of this, creating a spring module...etc for Wildfly

The spring are dependencies of the project, and jar are available, so why it doesn't work simply like this ?